# System.Security.Cryptography.KeyDerivation not being recognized in VS Community 2015 ver. 14.0.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hashcode, visual-studio-2015

For the life of me I cannot get Cryptography.KeyDerivation to be recognized in a template ASP.NET MVC application that has nothing changed. I have looked around and some show

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;

-or-

using Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;

-but even-

using System.Security.Cryptography.KeyDerivation; is not listed @

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I would like to take the code, which I found online to override the default version of PasswordHasher which uses HMACSHA1 and use HMACSHA526 instead, of:

```
string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: password,
        salt: salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
```

and use a prf of HMACSHA512 for the override of the base class of PasswordHasher which only has one constructor with the password to be passed in.

One last question once this accomplished instead of making a separate override class could I not just stick the code within ApplicationUserManager, here?

```
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store) 
{
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(input, salt, 10000);
string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256 / 8));
```

For me work wine. If use only KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1.

Comment: Even if that works, which I haven't tested, that is not what the question asks as I state I want to use HMACSHA526.